# Does scikit learn Pipeline apply StandardScaler to y?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

Given that my pipeline is

```
pipe = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('regressor', LinearRegression())])
```

And then I call `pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)`, does the pipeline apply the scaler to both features and target or only the features?

If not, what purpose does the `y` argument serve in the `fit_transform` method of the StandardScaler? The documentation is really confusing.
For `fit` it says that `y` is ignored. For `fit_transform` it says "Fits transformer to X **and** y". For `transform` it says `y` is deprecated.

I tried going through the source code on github, but quickly got lost jumping through chains of functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only the features get scaled. The confusion is understandable looking at the documentation. To convince yourself, run the pipeline with just the scaler and look at the output.