# SVR estimator contains no support vectors after training

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

When I use Scikit learn's SVR to fit some own data, the trained estimator ends up containing no support vectors and thus predicting always constant values. To my surprise, the same code work flawless when using some random training data. What is wrong with my code? Is there a problem with the data? (I also have lots of other data that shows the same problem.)

Here is a minimal example of the code, first with random training data. To make sure that the data can be fitted, I also added KernelRidge as reassurance. With the training data from random, every thing works fine:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn.kernel_ridge import KernelRidge
from sklearn.svm import SVR

# Random training data - works fine with both estimators
X = np.random.rand(50, 3) * 100
Y = [[np.sum(x), np.average(x)] for x in X]

# Kernel Ridge - works fine with both data
kernelRidgePipeline = Pipeline([('scale', StandardScaler()),
                                ('KernelRidge', KernelRidge(kernel='poly'))])
kernelRidgeGridsearch = GridSearchCV(kernelRidgePipeline, n_jobs=-1,
                                     param_grid={'KernelRidge__alpha': 10.0 ** -np.arange(1, 8),
                                                 'KernelRidge__degree': range(1, 5)})
kernelRidgeGridsearch.fit(X, Y)
print('Trained Kernel Ridge, cross-validation score: {:.2%}'.format(kernelRidgeGridsearch.best_score_))
#print(pd.DataFrame(kernelRidgeGridsearch.cv_results_))

# SVR - works fine with random data, empty support vectors after training with fixed data
SVRPipeline = Pipeline([('scale', StandardScaler()),
                        ('SVR', MultiOutputRegressor(SVR(kernel='rbf')))])
SVRGridsearch = GridSearchCV(SVRPipeline, n_jobs=-1,
                             param_grid={'SVR__estimator__C': np.logspace(-3, 3, 7),
                                         'SVR__estimator__gamma': np.logspace(-3, 3, 7)})
SVRGridsearch.fit(X, Y)
print('Trained SVR, cross-validation score: {:.2%}'.format(SVRGridsearch.best_score_))
#print(pd.DataFrame(SVRGridsearch.cv_results_))

best_svr_pipe = SVRGridsearch.best_estimator_
print([(estimator, estimator.support_vectors_) for estimator in best_svr_pipe.named_steps['SVR'].estimators_])
```

Executing above code, the output is as follows:

```
Trained Kernel Ridge, cross-validation score: 100.00%
Trained SVR, cross-validation score: 100.00%
[(SVR(C=1000.0, gamma=0.001), array([[-0.63418505, -1.59107071, -0.24340053],
       [-1.65336124, -0.57465634, -1.6026979 ],
       [-1.18120827,  0.82189646, -1.78927989],
       [-0.95929744,  1.56254011,  1.02792552],
       ...
```

Now, the problem starts to appear when I use the following training data instead:

```
# Own data - does not work with SVR
X = [[0.0009804, 0.004533 , 0.01827  , 0.007706 , 0.03145  , 0.01904  ],
     [0.05073  , 0.03821  , 0.03137  , 0.00321  , 0.04469  , 0.033    ],
     [0.03696  , 0.00544  , 0.04304  , 0.03579  , 0.01125  , 0.04032  ],
     [0.0515   , 0.01897  , 0.0      , 0.01897  , 0.0      , 0.0      ],
     [0.01897  , 0.01897  , 0.01897  , 0.0515   , 0.0      , 0.01897  ],
     [0.04704  , 0.02259  , 0.03783  , 0.008367 , 0.04813  , 0.05104  ],
     [0.0      , 0.01897  , 0.0      , 0.0515   , 0.01897  , 0.01897  ],
     [0.0      , 0.0      , 0.01897  , 0.01897  , 0.0      , 0.01897  ],
     [0.0      , 0.01897  , 0.0515   , 0.01897  , 0.0515   , 0.0515   ],
     [0.03163  , 0.02566  , 0.01027  , 0.02068  , 0.006748 , 0.02103  ],
     [0.003292 , 0.03846  , 0.02204  , 0.01941  , 0.01632  , 0.002126 ],
     [0.0515   , 0.0515   , 0.01897  , 0.01897  , 0.01897  , 0.0515   ],
     [0.0452   , 0.02487  , 0.0425   , 0.007782 , 0.001749 , 0.01841  ],
     [0.0515   , 0.0515   , 0.01897  , 0.0515   , 0.01897  , 0.0515   ],
     [0.0515   , 0.0      , 0.0515   , 0.01897  , 0.0      , 0.0515   ],
     [0.0      , 0.01897  , 0.0      , 0.0515   , 0.0      , 0.01897  ],
     [0.0      , 0.0515   , 0.01897  , 0.0      , 0.0      , 0.01897  ],
     [0.0515   , 0.0515   , 0.0515   , 0.01897  , 0.0515   , 0.01897  ],
     [0.0515   , 0.01897  , 0.0515   , 0.0515   , 0.0      , 0.0515   ],
     [0.01897  , 0.0515   , 0.01897  , 0.01897  , 0.0      , 0.0515   ],
     [0.0515   , 0.01897  , 0.0      , 0.0      , 0.0      , 0.0515   ],
     [0.04883  , 0.02794  , 0.01418  , 0.03165  , 0.01753  , 0.007313 ],
     [0.01073  , 0.009494 , 0.03339  , 0.001327 , 0.01707  , 0.01588  ],
     [0.04193  , 0.03918  , 0.007814 , 0.03498  , 0.002789 , 0.03957  ],
     [0.04872  , 0.04928  , 0.01344  , 0.03339  , 0.02326  , 0.02606  ],
     [0.00997  , 0.00993  , 0.03386  , 0.01935  , 0.006923 , 0.02288  ],
     [0.01897  , 0.01897  , 0.01897  , 0.0515   , 0.0      , 0.0515   ],
     [0.01897  , 0.0515   , 0.0515   , 0.0      , 0.01897  , 0.0      ],
     [0.008615 , 0.001054 , 0.04226  , 0.007394 , 0.002071 , 0.01514  ],
     [0.006528 , 0.04534  , 0.004602 , 0.01214  , 0.04099  , 0.02716  ],
     [0.0515   , 0.0515   , 0.0      , 0.0515   , 0.0515   , 0.0515   ],
     [0.04717  , 0.04847  , 0.02927  , 0.02849  , 0.04382  , 0.01184  ],
     [0.02146  , 0.03994  , 0.005115 , 0.02845  , 0.03113  , 0.02515  ],
     [0.003326 , 0.002409 , 0.04982  , 0.03079  , 0.02167  , 0.0116   ],
     [0.0      , 0.01897  , 0.01897  , 0.0515   , 0.0515   , 0.01897  ],
     [0.02106  , 0.01718  , 0.02647  , 0.01066  , 0.02419  , 0.002777 ],
     [0.02533  , 0.008516 , 0.05118  , 0.04527  , 0.008341 , 0.0012   ],
     [0.04721  , 0.001682 , 0.04941  , 0.0431   , 0.01283  , 0.03503  ],
     [0.01897  , 0.0      , 0.0515   , 0.0      , 0.01897  , 0.0515   ],
     [0.0      , 0.0515   , 0.0515   , 0.0515   , 0.0515   , 0.01897  ],
     [0.0      , 0.0      , 0.0515   , 0.01897  , 0.0515   , 0.0515   ],
     [0.0386   , 0.01649  , 0.02286  , 0.03572  , 0.005517 , 0.00382  ],
     [0.02654  , 0.01036  , 0.04756  , 0.04297  , 0.03086  , 0.03606  ],
     [0.01222  , 0.03092  , 0.01132  , 0.00487  , 0.0192   , 0.002185 ],
     [0.04892  , 0.03272  , 0.03173  , 0.04939  , 0.007464 , 0.02107  ],
     [0.0      , 0.0515   , 0.01897  , 0.0515   , 0.01897  , 0.0515   ],
     [0.0515   , 0.01897  , 0.0515   , 0.0      , 0.01897  , 0.0      ],
     [0.0      , 0.01897  , 0.01897  , 0.01897  , 0.0      , 0.0515   ],
     [0.01897  , 0.01897  , 0.0      , 0.01897  , 0.01897  , 0.01897  ],
     [0.049    , 0.02872  , 0.01126  , 0.03502  , 0.04904  , 0.04057  ]]
Y = [[0.008053 , 0.003143 , 0.006198 , 0.005975 , 0.008053 ],
     [0.007296 , 0.002185 , 0.003862 , 0.003294 , 0.007296 ],
     [0.006632 , 0.001999 , 0.005249 , 0.003463 , 0.006632 ],
     [0.01035  , 0.004031 , 0.006534 , 0.005148 , 0.01035  ],
     [0.007918 , 0.002983 , 0.005321 , 0.00498  , 0.007918 ],
     [0.006595 , 0.001628 , 0.003932 , 0.002831 , 0.006595 ],
     [0.007923 , 0.003134 , 0.005321 , 0.005976 , 0.007923 ],
     [0.009137 , 0.003162 , 0.006538 , 0.006061 , 0.009137 ],
     [0.005462 , 0.001916 , 0.004102 , 0.004758 , 0.005462 ],
     [0.009059 , 0.002799 , 0.00489  , 0.004375 , 0.009059 ],
     [0.007887 , 0.004124 , 0.005531 , 0.006745 , 0.007887 ],
     [0.007924 , 0.001586 , 0.002859 , 0.002664 , 0.007924 ],
     [0.008681 , 0.00287  , 0.005059 , 0.004109 , 0.008681 ],
     [0.006705 , 0.001586 , 0.002859 , 0.002664 , 0.006705 ],
     [0.007893 , 0.001608 , 0.005319 , 0.002746 , 0.007893 ],
     [0.009136 , 0.003134 , 0.005321 , 0.005976 , 0.009136 ],
     [0.01035  , 0.003072 , 0.004077 , 0.005832 , 0.01035  ],
     [0.005462 , 0.002805 , 0.004077 , 0.003883 , 0.005462 ],
     [0.006675 , 0.0016   , 0.004102 , 0.002717 , 0.006675 ],
     [0.009137 , 0.001731 , 0.002859 , 0.003662 , 0.009137 ],
     [0.01157  , 0.0016   , 0.004102 , 0.002717 , 0.01157  ],
     [0.007688 , 0.00351  , 0.005578 , 0.004669 , 0.007688 ],
     [0.008482 , 0.003219 , 0.006034 , 0.005567 , 0.008482 ],
     [0.00888  , 0.001983 , 0.003592 , 0.003275 , 0.00888  ],
     [0.007375 , 0.002475 , 0.003798 , 0.003609 , 0.007375 ],
     [0.007945 , 0.002865 , 0.005647 , 0.005245 , 0.007945 ],
     [0.007918 , 0.001765 , 0.004102 , 0.003762 , 0.007918 ],
     [0.007893 , 0.004163 , 0.00529  , 0.006093 , 0.007893 ],
     [0.00869  , 0.003287 , 0.006663 , 0.005751 , 0.00869  ],
     [0.00827  , 0.002649 , 0.003866 , 0.005098 , 0.00827  ],
     [0.006704 , 0.001586 , 0.002859 , 0.002664 , 0.006704 ],
     [0.005992 , 0.00322  , 0.004561 , 0.004387 , 0.005992 ],
     [0.007765 , 0.002648 , 0.00413  , 0.004514 , 0.007765 ],
     [0.006768 , 0.00354  , 0.006768 , 0.006256 , 0.00605  ],
     [0.005976 , 0.003134 , 0.005321 , 0.005976 , 0.005487 ],
     [0.007775 , 0.003974 , 0.006419 , 0.005899 , 0.007775 ],
     [0.007052 , 0.004071 , 0.007052 , 0.00587  , 0.006263 ],
     [0.0061   , 0.002139 , 0.005705 , 0.003364 , 0.0061   ],
     [0.007893 , 0.001781 , 0.00532  , 0.003819 , 0.007893 ],
     [0.005832 , 0.003072 , 0.004077 , 0.005832 , 0.004244 ],
     [0.005462 , 0.001944 , 0.00532  , 0.004843 , 0.005462 ],
     [0.007806 , 0.003801 , 0.006381 , 0.005206 , 0.007806 ],
     [0.005274 , 0.0022   , 0.005072 , 0.003956 , 0.005274 ],
     [0.009198 , 0.004064 , 0.005813 , 0.006297 , 0.009198 ],
     [0.00685  , 0.002716 , 0.004588 , 0.003867 , 0.00685  ],
     [0.006705 , 0.001854 , 0.002859 , 0.004614 , 0.006705 ],
     [0.007893 , 0.004031 , 0.006534 , 0.005148 , 0.007893 ],
     [0.009137 , 0.001916 , 0.004102 , 0.004758 , 0.009137 ],
     [0.009141 , 0.002983 , 0.005321 , 0.00498  , 0.009141 ],
     [0.006505 , 0.001927 , 0.003962 , 0.003081 , 0.006505 ]]
```

Using this training data, the output of the program is as follows:

```
Trained Kernel Ridge, cross-validation score: 96.32%
Trained SVR, cross-validation score: -46.40%
[(SVR(C=0.001, gamma=0.001), array([], shape=(0, 6), dtype=float64)), (SVR(C=0.001, gamma=0.001), array([], shape=(0, 6), dtype=float64)), (SVR(C=0.001, gamma=0.001), array([], shape=(0, 6), dtype=float64)), (SVR(C=0.001, gamma=0.001), array([], shape=(0, 6), dtype=float64)), (SVR(C=0.001, gamma=0.001), array([], shape=(0, 6), dtype=float64))]
```

If I uncomment `print(pd.DataFrame(SVRGridsearch.cv_results_))`, I can also see that the behavior is the same for all hyper-parameter combinations.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Edit my answer with a better solution; I initially had used `Y = [[np.sum(x), np.average(x)] for x in X]` with your `X` for debugging reasons and therefore didn't immediately realize that `Y` was the real culprit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited answer:**

The problem is that your `Y` is not scaled properly, see [this similar post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253825/scikit-learn-svr-prediction-output-is-constant) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272550/does-scikit-learn-pipeline-apply-standardscaler-to-y)

You could either change the parameter `epsilon` to 0.0001 or even lower, as in

`('SVR', MultiOutputRegressor(SVR(kernel='rbf', epsilon=0.0001)))`

or scale your `Y` by at least 1000.

Alternatively, you could try to get a StandardScaler to run on your `Y` with a [TransformedTargetRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html) as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63586995/sklearn-scaling-x-data-and-y-target-using-both-pipeline-and-transformedtar).